# Finding percentage of raster contained in shapefile using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, shapefile, arcgis-pro, intersection, statistics

Using ArcGIS Pro, I have a raster that shows tree height and a shapefile that contain parcels of land. I am trying to find out the percentage of the raster that intersects with the shapefile for each parcel. I am assuming that Zonal Statistics is the tool to use in this case, but I am not sure what to choose for each parameter, such as the zone field.

Is there a better tool to use or should I use this one and if so, what would the parameters be?

Comment: Do you care what values are contained within your polygon zones? For example, are you interested in getting at tree cover for each zone or whether or not any valid pixel is contained within the polygon?

Comment: any valid pixel, since all of the pixels represent tree cover

Comment: How would you like to handle NoData pixels?

Comment: I don't know. I guess mark them as 0

Comment: So I just performed a tabulate area with the parcels as the input feature zone data and the raster as the class field, including non-tree pixels. It seems like a good first step since the output table gives me a count of how many pixels of each value there are in each parcel. Now what I want to do is get a percentage of tree pixels there are in each parcel

Answer (score 0):

Tabulate Area tool. Use the shapefile as the input feature zone and object_ID as the zonal. Use the raster as the input class and value as the class. This generates a table showing a count of each pixel within each parcel. Export the table as an .csv file and open in excel. Create a column that calculates the percentage of pixels within each parcel.